# angular ngx-treeview from Json object error : A text of item must be string object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, treeview

**this treeview item text is confusing me for the past week**

this is how I load the items into the tree view:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.items = this.getItems([JSON.stringify(this.json_obj)]);
 }
 getItems(parentChildObj: any[]) {
   let itemsArray: TreeviewItem[] = [];
   parentChildObj.forEach((set: TreeItem) => {
     itemsArray.push(new TreeviewItem(set,true))
   });
   return itemsArray;
 }
```

and this is how I create the nested Json object from non-nested Json file :

```
this.departments.forEach(element => {
  if(element.ParentID == 0){
    p_counter++;
    this.json_obj.push(
      {
        text: element.DepartmentName ,
        value: 'p'+p_counter.toString() ,
        children: [],
        id: element.DepartmentID.toString() ,
      } as never
    );
    element.DepartmentName = 'fixed';
  }
});
```

the template is simple as that:

```
<ngx-treeview [items]="items" dir ="rtl"></ngx-treeview>
```

btw- it creates a perfect nesting but it cant read the object properties in
new TreeviewItem(set,true);
because it's undefined.

**Error : A text of item must be string object  at new TreeviewItem**

please help me figure this out, what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have used

```
        text: element.DepartmentName ,
        value: 'p'+p_counter.toString() ,
        children: [],
        id: element.DepartmentID.toString()
```

It seems you have not followed `TreeItem` interface given in `treeview-item.d.ts`

```
export interface TreeItem {
    text: string;
    value: any;
    disabled?: boolean;
    checked?: boolean;
    collapsed?: boolean;
    children?: TreeItem[];
}
```

you should remove `id` because that is not property of `TreeItem` interface.

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeviewItem } from 'ngx-treeview';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ngx-treeview [items]="items"></ngx-treeview>`
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    items: TreeviewItem[];
    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = this.getItems();
    }

    getItems(){
        // fetch api response
        // convert response into this format (object can be nested, should contain below keys only with given type)    
        // {
        //     text: string;
        //     value: any;
        //     disabled ?: boolean; 
        //     checked ?: boolean;
        //     collapsed ?: boolean;
        //     children ?: TreeItem[];
        // }

        const item = new TreeviewItem({
            text: 'Children', value: 1, children: [
                { text: 'Baby 3-5', value: 11 },
                { text: 'Baby 6-8', value: 12 },
                { text: 'Baby 9-12', value: 13 }
            ]
        });
        return [ item ];
    }
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngtreeview?file=src/app/app.component.ts)